# How to introduce myself to my teacher?

Tags: español-neutral, saludos

How can I introduce myself using Spanish language? Is this correct?

> Me llamo Marco. Mi nombre es Marco. Mi apellido es Cruz. Tengo 22 años. Soy filipino. Soy de Filipinas. Soy de Cebú. Hablo filipino, inglés, español. Nací el 15 de septiembre 1997.

Is there anything wrong? Any suggestions for improvement?

Answer (score 4):

If you say:

> Me llamo Marco

following then with `mi nombre es Marco` is redundant.

Instead of saying

> Mi nombre es Marco. Mi apellido es Cruz

You could say

> Mi nombre es Marco Cruz

Most people are going to understand what is your first name and last name. You don't need to clarify like that every time you introduce yourself.

The same goes for

> Soy filipino. Soy de Filipinas. Soy de Cebú

You could go with something like

> Soy filipino, de Cebú
>
> Soy de Cebú, Filipinas

Also, for a enumeration, like in many other languages, you use commas to separate all elements except for the last, which needs some sort of conjunction

> Hablo filipino, inglés **y** español

Comment: +1 To complete the corrections you should add "Nací el 15 de septiembre **de** 1997

Answer (score 2):

Me llamo Marco Cruz, tengo 22 años. Soy de Cebú, Filipinas. Además hablo inglés y español. Nací el 17 de septiembre de 1997.